# Android ARToolKit - Using image as output instead of a 3D model or a video?

Tags: android, artoolkit

I've been tinkering with the sample ARToolKit Android Studio projects. They all are very cool and promising, however, I noticed that they usually show the color gradient cube, use a 3D model of a car or a plane, or a video. I don't think I've seen an ARToolKit example that uses another image.

I thought of using the ARMovie example but just using a photo instead of an mp4 file but it didn't work. I'm not getting any error (because I fed a photo when it was probably expecting a video) but I didn't get any output either.

Has anyone tried to use a plain photo overlay as an output using ARToolKit?

Comment: Hi. It is possible but you might want to change to the Unity Branch and just export it to android. Unity comes with a comfortable editor where you can drag an RawImage instead of the cube onto the marker.